Python Gekko ignores variable types
With this code
from gekko import GEKKO

model = GEKKO(remote=False)

x = model.Var(name='x', lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)
y = model.Var(name='y', lb=0, ub=10, integer=True)
z = model.Var(name='z')

model.Equation(x + y + z >= 10)
model.Equation(y - 2 * z <= 5)

model.Obj(x + 2 * y + 3 * z)

model.options.SOLVER=3 

model.solve(disp=False)

print(f"{x.name:>5s} = {x.value[0]:8.4f}")
print(f"{y.name:>5s} = {y.value[0]:8.4f}")
print(f"{z.name:>5s} = {z.value[0]:8.4f}")
print(f"{'obj':>5s} = {model.options.OBJFCNVAL:8.4f}")

I get the result:
int_x =   1.0000
int_y =   7.6667
    z =   1.3333
  obj =  20.3333

Why is integer=True ignored? I expect to get
1
7
2
21


Actual problem is not in gekko, but here print(f"{x.name:>5s} = {x.value[0]:8.4f}"), it is how string formatting works, you are printing out a digit rounded to 4 decimal. So, if you print(f"{1:.4f}") it displays 1.0000 .

Set the solver to APOPT as a Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming solver to find an integer solution: m.options.SOLVER=1 or m.options.SOLVER='APOPT'. The solver selected by default is the IPOPT Nonlinear Programming (NLP) solver as SOLVER option 3. This returns an integer solution for x, but a non-integer solution for y as you observed.
